# Javascript callback after on change event has partial page refresh

Tags: javascript

I am using a web framework which uses partial page rendering to refresh a part of a screen using the change event of a input field. I don't have access to the function for the change event, but I can inject jquery to add my own change event for that field. Unfortunately the field is also refreshed in the partial page rendering.

I am trying to inject my own code to add some styling to that part of the page. Unfortunately the `$(document).ready` only fires once at the beginning, so when the partial page refresh happens my code gets lost.

If I use `$(document).change` or attach directly to the change event of the input field my code fires before the framework's change and partial page refresh and therefore also gets lost.

So the only thing I could get to work is to wait 3 seconds with a callback and then apply my code again. This is however very ugly and on slow machines it sometimes needs more than 3 seconds.

Is there any way of attaching a callback to the change event that fires after the partial page refresh.

The framework uses very old web standards (table layout) and also tends to `return false` on a lot of it's change function's. Not sure if this will prevent any further propogation, that is to say prevent my callback.

This is the input element:

```
<input id="N24:MiscRt1:0" title="Miscellaneous Rate 1" class="xa" onchange="_uixspu('DefaultFormName',1,'DynCalcUpd','MiscRt1',0,1,{'_FORM_SUBMIT_BUTTON':'_fwkActBtnName_MiscRt1_DynCalcUpdYAS-AIio','evtSrcRowId':'AllocationsAM.AllocationsPlanVO321831001-132183-321838243CWBASG8243CWBPERFAPPRAISALOSCgK_CA','DynCalcUpdCol':'Misc1ValUGoCYJgF','evtSrcRowIdx':'06cW78OeE'});return true;" name="N24:MiscRt1:0" size="10" type="text" value="0.00" maxlength="38">
```

This is the code I tried:

```
function xxcwb_func() {
   $('span#CompTable table.x1n:nth-child(1) tbody tr td input').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $('span#CompTable table.x1n:nth-child(1) tbody tr td select').on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
   });
   $('span#CompTable table.x1n:nth-child(1) tbody tr td').on('click', function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('xxcwb_highlight')) {
         $(this).parent().find('td').css('background', '#f2f2f5');
         $(this).parent().find('td').removeClass('xxcwb_highlight');
      }
      else {
         $(this).parent().parent().find('td').css('background', '#f2f2f5').removeClass('xxcwb_highlight');
         $(this).parent().find('td').css('background', '#97cbf6');
         $(this).parent().find('td').addClass("xxcwb_highlight");
      }
   });
   addSeparator('Current Salary');
   addSeparator('Proposed Increase Amount');
   addSeparator('PDD New Salary');
   addSeparator('Proposed Salary');
   addSeparator('LM New Salary');
   addSeparator('HR New Salary');
   addSeparator('CEO New Salary');
   addSeparator('Current Car Benefit');
   addSeparator('Current Total Cash');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   // Run our code.
   xxcwb_func();
});

$(document).change(function() {
   xxcwb_func();
});
```

The callback also has to wait for the other change function and the partial page refresh to finish first.

Comment: Please add your code that you have tried

Comment: If you mean ajax by partial refresh, you can do your stuffs in success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).change(function() {
    window.setTimeout(xxcwb_func,0);
});
```

This will push it to the browsers TODO list (with a due date specified in the second argument), which it will get around to doing after the partial page refresh occurs.

Comment: Try changing the "0" to some bigger number (It's a millisecond delay).  It should work if it's big enough. I commonly also use 20, 50, 100, etc.

Comment: Onchage is inputs only form event.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
setInterval(function{
  /* check if the element is already "evented" */
  if (!$("#myelement").data("alreadyEvented")) {
    /* set the flag that it is ok now: element is evented */
    $("#myelement").data("alreadyEvented","true");
    $("#myelement").click(function{ /* or another event */
      /* your event */
    });
  }
},50);
```

it is simple, dumb, and should be working :)

after partial refresh the attribute will be removed as well -> event will be assigned again